# How to get pyPdf to work with os or glob

Tags: python, parsing, pypdf

My goal is to read a directory with several PDF files and return the number of pages in each file using Python. I'm trying to use the pyPdf library but it fails.

If I do this:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

testFile = "C:\\path\\file.pdf"
pdfFile = PdfFileReader(file(testFile, 'rb'))
print pdfFile.getNumPages()
```

I'll get a result

If I do this, it fails:

```
pdfList = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\path"):
   for file in files:
     pdfList.append(os.path.join(root, file)

for item in pdfList:
  targetPdf = PdfFileReader(file(item,'rb'))
  numPages = targetPdf.getNumPages()
  print item, numPages
```

This always results in:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

If I try to recreate a pyPdf object manually, I get the same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is due to using name, file as variable.
You are using file as variable name in first for loop.
And as a function call in statement, targetPdf = PdfFileReader(file(item,'rb')).

Try changing variable name in first for loop from file to fileName.
Hope that helps

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. That fixed it immediately. Thanks for the tip.